# Go mod troubles with terraform module that builds golang binaries

Tags: go, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, go-modules

I'm on the last step of a side project, and I can't get terraform to build my golang binaries now that I'm trying to deploy my code as a terraform module.

My terraform module invocation looks like this.

```
module "moot" {
  source = "github.com/seanturner026/moot.git"

  name                           = "moot"
  admin_user_email               = "blah@example.com"
  enable_delete_admin_user       = false
  github_token                   = "42"
  gitlab_token                   = "42"
  slack_webhook_url              = "42"
  fqdn_alias                     = ""
  hosted_zone_name               = ""
  enable_api_gateway_access_logs = false
  tags                           = { Name = "moot" }
}
```

For some reason, go modules is messing with my `null_resource`s which I use to build my golang lambda binaries when I deploy via the module.

This module invocation builds a whole heap of things, but you can build pretty minimal resources and still hit the error with the following command.

`terraform apply -target='module.moot.null_resource.lambda_build["users"]'`

Running this command errors out with the following:

```
module.moot.null_resource.lambda_build["users"]: Creating...
module.moot.null_resource.lambda_build["users"]: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
module.moot.null_resource.lambda_build["users"] (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "export GO111MODULE=on"]
module.moot.null_resource.lambda_build["users"]: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
module.moot.null_resource.lambda_build["users"] (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "GOOS=linux go build -ldflags '-s -w' -o .terraform/modules/moot/bin/users .terraform/modules/moot/cmd/users/."]
module.moot.null_resource.lambda_build["users"] (local-exec): no required module provides package .terraform/modules/moot/cmd/users: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'
```

The `null_resource` code is located here https://github.com/seanturner026/moot/blob/e51aee51d12472735e6bc5902e54dd603f750aff/r_lambda.tf#L1-L23

The example which uses a module source of `../../` (rather than the github link) does work successfully. I'm not sure why, but perhaps it's because `go.mod` is in an upper directory? Either way, that example is deployable here, and the above `terraform apply` command works https://github.com/seanturner026/moot/blob/stackoverflow/terraform_examples/complete/main.tf

I've also got a makefile located here https://github.com/seanturner026/moot/blob/stackoverflow/Makefile. Running `make build` also fails

```
$ make build
export GO111MODULE=on
env GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o bin/auth         cmd/auth/. &
env GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o bin/releases     cmd/releases/. &
env GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o bin/repositories cmd/repositories/. &
env GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o bin/users        cmd/users/. &
package cmd/auth is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/cmd/auth)
package cmd/releases is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/cmd/releases)
package cmd/repositories is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/cmd/repositories)
package cmd/users is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/cmd/users)
```

How do I go about fixing this problem? I recently renamed the repo, could that be causing issues?

Here's the directory layout when I'm specifying `github.com/seanturner026/moot.git` as the module invocation source.

```
.
├── .terraform
│   └── modules
│       └── moot
│           ├── .editorconfig
│           ├── .gitignore
│           ├── Makefile
│           ├── README.md
│           ├── archive
│           ├── assets
│           │   ├── repositories-add.png
│           │   ├── repositories.png
│           │   └── users.png
│           ├── bin
│           │   └── users
│           ├── cmd
│           │   ├── auth
│           │   │   ├── events.json
│           │   │   ├── login.go
│           │   │   ├── login_test.go
│           │   │   ├── main.go
│           │   │   ├── reset_password.go
│           │   │   └── reset_password_test.go
│           │   ├── releases
│           │   │   ├── event.json
│           │   │   ├── github.go
│           │   │   ├── gitlab.go
│           │   │   ├── main.go
│           │   │   └── main_test.go
│           │   ├── repositories
│           │   │   ├── create.go
│           │   │   ├── create_test.go
│           │   │   ├── delete.go
│           │   │   ├── delete_test.go
│           │   │   ├── events.json
│           │   │   ├── list.go
│           │   │   ├── list_test.go
│           │   │   └── main.go
│           │   └── users
│           │       ├── create.go
│           │       ├── create_test.go
│           │       ├── delete.go
│           │       ├── delete_test.go
│           │       ├── events.json
│           │       ├── list.go
│           │       ├── list_test.go
│           │       └── main.go
│           ├── data.tf
│           ├── go.mod
│           ├── go.sum
│           ├── internal
│           │   └── util
│           │       ├── generate_response_body.go
│           │       ├── generate_secret_hash.go
│           │       ├── main.go
│           │       └── post_to_slack.go
│           ├── locals.tf
│           ├── modules.tf
│           ├── outputs.tf
│           ├── r_acm.tf
│           ├── r_api_gateway.tf
│           ├── r_cloudwatch.tf
│           ├── r_cognito.tf
│           ├── r_dynamodb.tf
│           ├── r_iam.tf
│           ├── r_lambda.tf
│           ├── r_null.tf
│           ├── r_route53.tf
│           ├── r_s3.tf
│           ├── r_ssm.tf
│           ├── terraform_assets
│           │   ├── cognito.go
│           │   ├── cognito_invite_template.html
│           │   └── dynamodb_put_item_input.json
│           └── variables.tf
├── .terraform.lock.hcl
├── main.tf
├── provider.tf
├── terraform.auto.tfvars
├── terraform.tfstate
├── terraform.tfstate.backup
├── terraform.tfvars
└── variables.tf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

needed to put a `./` in front of the cmd binaries in the `null_resource` that builds the lambda binaries

Also needed to copy go.mod to the top level directory with another `null_resource`

https://github.com/seanturner026/moot/pull/6/commits/3ff8e18c5449f610eb9ca99c8e89bd31717a8bd9